# To remove character from Perl Regex

Tags: regex, perl

In Perl, I have a variable:

```
$var = 1M;
```

But I want `$var` to be only `1`. I dont want `M` in `$var`. So I am using regular expression in Perl as:

```
$var = s/M/;
```

But its not working.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$var = s/M/` and `$var = 1M` are not valid Perl expressions (barewords excepted). If that is how you really wrote it in your code, that is one of the problems. If not, then please fix it. It is careless to post approximate code when asking a question.

Comment: `$var = s/M//` is short for `$var = $_ =~ s/M//`.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to add the replacement part. Syntax for substitution code would be `$variable =~ s/regex/replacement-string/modifier` . Add `g` modifier in the below code if you want the replacement to occur globally.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $var = "1M";
$var =~ s/M//;
print "$var\n";
```

Output:

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used wrong syntax for substitution . Try using use strict; and use warnings;

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $var = "1M";
$var =~ s/M//;

print $var;
```

Comment: Srry I forgot the  tilde ~ symbol and have modified it now... Thanks for the info @mpapec

Answer (score 0):

```
$var=~s/M//g;
```

This should work.
I would suggest to  read some good tutorial first.